# MBCalendarKit Faulty Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, mbcalendarkit

I am having a problem with the frame of my `CKCalendarView's` frame (Which comes with `MBCalendarKit`).

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see from the first and second pictures (and a little bit from the third too), the events are beginning to list way below the calendar. Which does not happen with framework's demo project.

The code I initialize it is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    calendarView = [CKCalendarView new];
    [calendarView setDisplayMode:CKCalendarViewModeDay];
    [[self calendarViewArea] addSubview:calendarView];
}
```

The calendarViewArea is a `UIView` which starts right below my `Navigation Bar`. This is because when I add the calendarView directly to my `ViewController's` view its top part stays below my navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of MBCalendarKit.

Although the newer versions of MBCalendarKit are better at supporting the larger screened iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, there's no official iPad support.

Try the new 3.0.4 release, for example. Build it to the iPad simulator. It seems to work well, but if you "rotate" the device, it breaks the cell layout.

I'm unsure if I'll add official support in the future, but it's a known bug and
you should follow issue [#31](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/issues/31) if you're interested in this feature.